Can I use an oscillating saw to cut an arched opening in a hollow-core door?
I’m trying to cut an arched cat door shape into a cheap (hollowish) door. I have a plastic cover to apply after cutting it out so I do not need a perfect shape, just close enough. Will an oscillating saw, handled by someone who has zero experience, do the trick or do I need to invest in a jigsaw?

This is opinion-based so it's not an answer but a comment: sure. Go slow, aim for a smaller hole that you need to finish out rather than a bigger one that is too big.

do you have experience with a jigsaw?

Jigsaw is the usually recommended tool, yes.

With the slimmest blade you can find.

An oscillator would be difficult to cut a curve with.  You might be able to cut a curve by doing the door skin on each side at a time.

Is your oscillating saw one in which the blade moves forward and back from the handle with a large stroke, or one in which it rotates rapidly side-to-side like a cast-removal tool?

Sure. A "jiggle" saw would make quick work of the soft skin of a hollow-core door.
Mark your opening. Then, using a curved blade oriented toward the door surface, begin tracing the mark. Imagine a pizza wheel rolling along the line.
Work in several passes until you cut through. The cut will be fairly clean, with no more than about 1/2" of tapered edge outside the original mark. The pet door trim should easily cover that. For safety, also mark the extent of the trim in advance as a reminder.
You could also just use the small end of a T-shaped blade, but it might be difficult to hold position and not slip out or drop too deep.

An oscillating saw is slower than a jig saw, so it won't deviate from the cut line as fast.
The oscillating saw does not bounce around much, whereas a jig saw can bounce terribly if not held firmly.
If rounded corners are needed, they can be achieved with a drill and a spade bit or hole saw, and the oscillating saw can cut straight between the edges of the holes.
A jig saw's blade may be long enough to do both sides of the door at once. However, a jig saw often carries the blade at an slight tilt, so the cut point at the far side of the door is slightly different than the cut point on the near side. Some jig saws have adjustments to remove this tilt, but not having the tilt changes the cut stroke and may make the cut harder to an inexperienced hand. This change may not be a problem cutting a hollow-core door.
You'll have to judge whether you can use a jig saw (you might borrow one to try on thin scrap wood) or you should use the oscillating saw.

Which oscillating tool are you envisioning? This reads like an answer for an oscillating multitool, but my read of the question was that the OP has something more like a sawzall.

@RLH I had in mind a tool where the blade pivots back and forth in an arc, not more than some 16th or 18th inch stroke. A google search "oscillating saw" turns up what I have seen and used. It's a really interesting saw: it cuts wood, not you. One can touch the cutting edge while the saw is on and not get cut. But it goes through wood easily. Skin wiggles back and forth too, but wood etc does not.

nod. I’ve heard people less-familiar with tools refer to reciprocating/sawzall saws as “oscillating”. Reciprocating saws at least used to be a more common item to own, and an item for which a jigsaw would be a clear “precision upgrade”, so I want to make sure we’re answering the question with the right comparison.
